# How to clear other apps data from my app programmetically

Tags: android

I found this from other answer

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear PACKAGE_NAME");
```

but this is working for own app only, i can not clear data of other app using this.

Will this work after converting my app as system app?

Do we have any official link on how to create system app and test it?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done without Root Permissions for oblivious security reasons.
System Apps can execute few actions more than User Apps however they don't have access to other folders.
Imagine an App that could clear all 3rd App's data...it could be very dangerous.